# How to make near-duplicates removal code go faster?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, duplicates, jupyter-notebook

I am using tweets to create word embeddings. I already removed complete duplicates, but now I also need to remove near-duplicates, let's say that if 5 tweets in my corpus have 80% overlap, only 1 of them should be kept. I am using the levenshtein.normalized_similarity() distance measure from the textdistance library to loop through my tweets. However, this takes forever... How can I make it faster? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

In the code below the df dataframe consists of the variables tweet ID (ID) en the tweet itself (SentimentText_Clean, type: string). In every iteration, the first tweet is selected and compared with all the other tweets remaining. Then the selected tweet is removed from the original dataframe and added to a new one. If the similarity is larger than the threshold value, the tweets are removed from the dataframe. The indices are reset and the a new first tweet is selected.

I already tried other distance measures as well, but that doesn't seem to work much faster. Also, I tried to remove just the retweets, but that is not exactly what I need. Further, I tried using lists instead of pandas but also that doesn't seem to be much faster.

```
import textdistance

def remove_near_duplicates(df, threshold = 0.8):

   new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ID", "SentimentText_Clean", 
                                  "Sim"])

   while len(df) > 0: 

      comp = df["SentimentText_Clean"][0]
      t_id = df["Tweet_ID"][0]
      df["Sim"] = df["SentimentText_Clean"].apply(lambda x: 
        textdistance.levenshtein.normalized_similarity(comp, x))
      new_df = new_df.append(df.iloc[[0]])
      df = df.iloc[1:]
      df = df.loc[df["Sim"] < threshold]
      df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)

   return new_df
```

Comment: You can try `symspellpy`, it is quite faster and give distance for a word from many.
`!pip install symspellpy`
Github: `https://github.com/mammothb/symspellpy/`